# How to create index in SQL to increase performance

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have around 200,000 rows in database table. When I execute my search query, it's taking around 4-5 seconds to give me results in next page. I want that execution should be fast and results should be loaded under 2 seconds. I have around 16 columns in my table.

Following is my query for creation of table

```
Create table xml(
PID int not null,
Percentdisc int not null,
name varchar(100) not null,
brand varchar(30) not null,
store varchar(30) not null,
price int not null,
category varchar(20) not null,
url1 varchar(300) not null,
emavail varchar(100) not null,
dtime varchar(100) not null,
stock varchar(30) not null,
description varchar(200) not null,
avail varchar(20) not null,
tags varchar(30) not null,
dprice int not null,
url2 varchar(300),
url3 varchar(300),
sid int primary key auto_increment);
```

Select query which I'm using

```
select * from feed where (name like '%Baby%' And NAME like '%Bassinet%')
```

I dont have much knowledge of indexing the database, to increase performance. Please guide me what index to use.

Comment: You are using two likes in your query, AFAIK that's not [indexable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html). I think you might be able to optimize one of the likes away (which should improve your performance). Also, you can try running [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) on your queries.

Comment: You could reconsider your WHERE clause: `where name like '%Baby%Bassinet%'` or `where name like '%Bassinet%Baby%'`

Comment: @MihaiBejenariu-The query given by you will be indexable?

Comment: -1 Tagging `mysql` and `sql-server`.

Comment: Please clarify whether you are using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server, rather than re-asking the question.

Answer (score 3):

Indexes aren't going to help. LIKE is a non sargable operator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: means,if i m using like in my query then indexing cant be done on that query.is it?

Comment: LIKE is non sargable only if it is with leading wildcard character ..more are characters before 1st % character better is index usage....

Comment: k.if i remove % sign before baby and bassinet and keep % signs after these words,query should be indexable.is it?

Comment: Yes. For this to work as it is now you must look into full text indices (and their corresponding queries), normal indices can not work with a beginning %.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good read [here](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

LIKE does not use the full text indexing. If you want to use full text searching you can use MySQL full text search functions, You can read [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) doc regarding this.

Here's the syntax for adding INDEX in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `feed`   
  ADD INDEX (`Name`);
```

MySQL Match example:

Substring matches: (Matches: Babylonian, Bassineete etc.)

```
SELECT * FROM `feed` WHERE MATCH (NAME) AGAINST ("+Baby* +Bassinett*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Exact matches:

```
SELECT * FROM `feed` WHERE MATCH (NAME) AGAINST ("+Baby +Bassinett" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: how should i create an index which i will add with this query

Comment: k.do i need to use only alter query or substring query also @jomsk1e

Comment: Add Index to column 'NAME' using ALTER TABLE `feed` Add INDEX(`Name`)... And use substring match or exact match in your query depending on your needs..

Comment: k.means i shud 2 queries ryt. one will be select query which u have given for substring and one alter query.

Comment: you only need to add index once.

Comment: k.means only alter query is it?

Comment: Run the alter query once to add index, then use the select query whenever you need it.

Comment: just asking on a lighter note.will this query make loading time<2seconds.is it?

Comment: You can try it yourself and get back once you checked.

Comment: i tried it with alter query and i used the same query by removing % sign before baby and bassinet.but still its taking too much time..

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard opeartor `%` used in starting of matching string renders any index created useless .

More are the characters before 1st wildcard operator , faster is the index lookup scan .

Anyways you can add an index to existing table

```
ALTER TABLE feed ADD INDEX (NAME);
```

This will have no index usage even after creating index on NAME column becuse it has a leading % character

```
select * from feed where (name like '%Baby%' And NAME like '%Bassinet%')
```

This will use indexing as starting % removed

```
select * from feed where (name like 'Baby%' And NAME like 'Bassinet%')
```

Comment: It means last query which u have mentioned in ur post,will be indexable,correct?

Comment: k.sir.can u please guide me on how shud i create an index on this table to read the data quickly....

Comment: see the alter table statement above

Comment: Thats only what do i need to do for indexing sir.or some other query also i need to design!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In your case index is not usefull. When we find with like operator it not use index. When we direct search i.e columnname = 'Ajay', at this time it search in index(if apply). The reason is index is searching with the physical data ,not with logical data(for like operator).

You can use Full-text search for this where you can define only those column in which you need to find data. FTS is usefull and get faster data when more data as you have.

How to enable FTS, please check the link.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Comment: But if i remove % sign before the word like if i keep it as baby%,then index should work.ryt?

Comment: No, % means wild card , so we get the result which start from baby , but end with "baby" or "baby ballon" or "baby123" . So index simple search the current data which on leaf of index.        As I wrote, for % microsoft introduce FTS which is faster than like operator.