# Query taking time after Indexing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have around 200000 rows in database table,when i execute my search query,its taking around 4-5 seconds to give me results in next page.I want that execution should be fast and page should be loaded in less than 2 secs.
Following is the table design

```
Create table xml(
PID int not null,
Percentdisc int not null,
name varchar(100) not null,
brand varchar(30) not null,
store varchar(30) not null,
price int not null,
category varchar(20) not null,
url1 varchar(300) not null,
emavail varchar(100) not null,
dtime varchar(100) not null,
stock varchar(30) not null,
description varchar(200) not null,
avail varchar(20) not null,
tags varchar(30) not null,
dprice int not null,
url2 varchar(300),
url3 varchar(300),
sid int primary key auto_increment);
```

select query used

```
select * from xml where (name like '%women%)
```

Index query used to add in table

```
alter table xml add index(NAME)
```

But still loading time is 4-5 secs.Please guide on this...

Comment: Rather than using LIKE in this case, when you're searching for an occurrence of a word anywhere within the column, consider [Full Text Indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Is your table InnoDB or MyIsam?

Comment: tht i havent given sir,which one shud i give to load sql query

Comment: @Dieter-as i was not aware of db engines

Comment: This question is nearly a copy-and-paste duplicate of [how to create index in sql to increase performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284372/how-to-create-index-in-sql-to-increase-performance), which you asked four hours before this one.

Comment: ya.that was a different question and now i m getting a differnt issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your index will do very little for performance because you're doing a LIKE '%something%'.
It will still have to scan through all the content of your name of your entire table to be able to find records where the value is located.
So you've properly just replaced your table scan with an index scan.

The only way an index will help is if you can do a LIKE 'something%' in that situation.

So you might have to rethink your structure to get what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `LIKE` keyword, if the text start with `%`, no indexes could be used

Comment: i tried with deleting the starting % sign,time is reduced,but i want it be less than 2 seconds.anything more can be done fr that sir.